Why this y.load can happens before y.store under this Acquire-release memory order
I'm reading "C++ concurrency in action", and I'm reading about the code in the section of ACQUIRE-RELEASE ORDERING, the example is
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;
void write_x()
{
 x.store(true,std::memory_order_release);
}
void write_y()
{
 y.store(true,std::memory_order_release);
}
void read_x_then_y()
{
 while(!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
 if(y.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) # 1
 ++z;
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
 while(!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
 if(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) # 2
 ++z;
}
int main()
{
 x=false;
 y=false;
 z=0;
 std::thread a(write_x);
 std::thread b(write_y);
 std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
 std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
 a.join();
 b.join();
 c.join();
 d.join();
 assert(z.load()!=0); 
}

then, the author's analysis is

In this case the assert "assert(z.load()!=0); " can fire (like in the relaxed-ordering case), because it’s possible for both the load of x (in remark 2) and the load of y (in remark 1) to read false. x and y are written by different threads, so the ordering from the release to the acquire in each case has no effect on the operations in the other threads.Figure 5.6 shows the happens-before relationships from the code, along with a possible outcome where the two reading threads each have a different view of the
world. This is possible because there’s no happens-before relationship to force an ordering, as described previously, the figure 5.6 is ,

I can't understand whay the y.load can happens before y.store in the second subset of figure5.6 from left to right,according to the book, the release with this memory order synchronize with the acquire, so the y.store should happens before the y.load, and also Acquire-release ordering is a step up from relaxed ordering; there’s still no total order of operations, so does the property that "there’s still no total order of operations" calls that the y.load can happens before y.store?

It says that no happens-before relationship exists, in either direction. "Happens-before" does not have the common English language meaning. It is a term used for a specific mathematical relationship between expressions.

There is no global time order in which things happen. From the point of view of each thread the order in which stores happen can be different. That's the point.

There simply is no direct or indirect synchronization between the threads read_x_then_y and read_y_then_x at all. None of the evaluations in either thread happen-before any evaluation in the other thread and therefore there is no restriction that would force the values read for x and y in the two threads to be consistently ordered with one another.

"the release with this memory order synchronize with the acquire, so the y.store should happens before the y.load": This doesn't follow. There is no rule in the memory model from which you could make that deduction.

If the loads & stores use a single total order in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order, then your (and mine) intuition would be correct.  Such a sequentially consistent ordering is called std::memory_order_seq_cst.

An acquire doesn't "synchronize" with any release.
memory_order

Synchronizes with
If an atomic store in thread A is a release operation, an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is an acquire operation, and the load in thread B reads a value written by the store in thread A, then the store in thread A synchronizes-with the load in thread B.

emphasis mine.
Only if thread 2 reads the value written by thread 1 will thread 2 be synchronized with thread 1, but it still has nothing to do with thread 3 or thread 4, it is not synchronized with them, simply because it didn't read a value written by them.
Imagine a machine with 2 cores and 4 hyper-threads.
core 1 has the first two threads, it stores x=true and spins until it reads x=true but it can read either y=true or y=false, because it is not synchronized with thread 4.
in the exact same time on core 2 the other two threads are running and also writes y = true and spins until it reads y = true but it can read x = true or x = false, because it didn't synchronize with thread 1, maybe the store in core 1 hasn't reached the main memory yet or it is still in the store buffers, or the cache is still being flushed, etc ...
The stores having no total order caused one thread to observe x=0, y=1 and the other to observe x=1, y=0 the stores to x and y have different order for different observers, that's what it means to have no total ordering.
The remedy here is to use sequentially consistent loads and stores so that all the loads and stores will have a consistent total ordering, even if they don't read or write to the same variables.
